# Assigning Boolean from Object from Hashtable in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, casting, boolean, hashtable

Just moving to Java, so please forgive this basic question:

After this:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> ht = (Hashtable<String, Object>) menus.get(position);
String title = (String) ht.get("title");
Boolean isCategory = (Boolean) ht.get("isCatgory");
```

The value of ht is `{isCategory=true, title=Info}`, as expected.
The value of title is `"Info"`, as expected.
The value of isCategory is `null`.

How can I extract the Boolean from the Hashtable?

Comment: Please don't do that! A `Hashtable` is not a valid replacement for your own class.

Comment: Actually: this is the **perfect** example of **why** you want to write your own class for this: the *compiler* should be able to tell you what the problem is here, but it can't, because you have chosen to use a `Hashtable` instead of a proper class.

Comment: You are right! I did not want to go trough the notions for a very small class. But it is less code than I expected. Same problem as with KVC in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Boolean isCategory = (Boolean) ht.get("isCategory");//you left **"e"**
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to buy a vowel.

```
ht.get("isCategory");  // notice the "e"
```